# SQL - Count per Person

Tags: sql

Using MySQL
Lets say I have records in a table with columns:
PersonName, ProjectType

PersonName contains names of people.
ProjectType contains types of projects, i.e. Software, Mechanical, etc.

### Goal:

I want to SELECT from that table to get the number of projects per person.
I need both number of projects total, and number of projects per type.

### How do I write the SQL for this?

1. Number of Total Projects, per Person
2. Number of Projects Per ProjectType, per Person

I want to be able to get the data in PersonName, #ofProjects format.

I tried looking at similar questions/answers, but im not quite getting the information I want from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of Total Projects, per Person

```
select
  person, count(*) as TotalProjectsPerPerson
from
  table
group by person
```

Number of Projects Per ProjectType, per Person

```
select
  person, projecttype, count(*) as TotalProjectsPerTypePerPerson
from
  table
group by person, projecttype
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT PersonName,
       count(ProjectType) As NumberOfProjectsPerPerson
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY PersonName
```

This would fetch you the number of projects per person.

Use `count(distinct ProjectType)` if there can be different projects in one
ProjectType and you need irrespective of it.

```
select
  PersonName, ProjectType, count(*) as TotalProjectsPerTypePerPerson
from
  TABLE
group by PersonName, ProjectType
```

would fetch you Number of Projects Per ProjectType, per Person.

Comment: It kind of looks like you copied from my answer.  I do like the `distinct` comment however.  So here's a +1 in hopes that you return the favor and give credit where it's due.

Comment: I am sorry if you felt so, but it would be dumb to copy. I am just surfing around.

Comment: Its not a problem at all, it just seems odd that you have such a long alias that happens to be the same as mine. I'll take your word for it.  My real motivation was just trying to get an upvote from you. :)